# React Native use Android Studio Setup SDK 33.0.0 Not found

Tags: react-native, android-studio

$ npx react-native doctor
⠹ Running diagnostics...* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

- daemon started successfully
  Common
  ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
  ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies

Android
✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

- Versions found: N/A
- Version supported: 33.0.0
  ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

Comment: Are you using zsh or bash ? Can your post your zsh.rc or bash.rc?